# how to enable/disable a textbox based on dropdown list value

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 dropdown list values and  for 1 of it when selected I want the one textbox out of 2 to get disabled.

```
         protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
          if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue=="Admin")
            TextBox2.Enabled = false;
           else
            TextBox2.Enabled = true;
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
          if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()=="Admin")
            TextBox2.Enabled = false;
           else
            TextBox2.Enabled = true;
           }
```

Example:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
               <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="1" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="2" />
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

If do you want to use Value, you can use "DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()=="1""

If do you want to use Text, you can use "DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()=="Admin" "